# How to get Boolean variable in Regular expressions Swift 4

Tags: regex, swift, expression

I'm trying to make a regular expression that looks for an e-mail. Everything works . How to get a `Bool` variable that would mean whether such an expression was found or not?

```
let someString = "123milka@yandex.ru123"

let regexp = "([a-zA-Z]{1,20})@([a-zA-Z]{1,20}).(com|ru|org)"

if let range = someString.range(of: regexp, options: .regularExpression) {
    let result : String = someString.substring(with: range)

    print(result)
}
```

Comment: FYI - your regular expression will match `===hello@example.com====` or any other email address with garbage at either end.

Comment: Also note that your regular expression will not match the example email address in your question. You might also want to consider using data detectors if you want to detect email addresses within a string.

Comment: If this is not longer a duplicate then you need to explain why it is different

Answer (score 2):

You already have an `if` test, so use that, setting your Boolean as you see fit. There are tons of ways of doing that, e.g.:

```
let success: Bool

if let range = someString.range(of: regexp, options: .regularExpression) {
    success = true
    let result = someString.substring(with: range)
    print(result)
} else {
    success = false
}
```

Comment: Oh, I made a stupid mistake. Thank you for your help, dear friend.